# CubieBoard Sound Driver

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, linux-device-driver, cortex-a8, linaro

I'm using CubieBoard 1(A10), it have an Image of Linux Linaro to Run from MicroSD on its DVD. it has the sound drivers for HDMI and AUX Jack. in the "/proc/asound" there are some folders "Card0, Card1, Sun4iCodec, sun4isndhdmi". and I can Play Sounds and get the output from AUX Jack.

the problem is I need to build the kernel of Linux myself, so when I tried, the drivers would not install. I Included all of the sound Drivers in kernel, I tried every thing I could, but it doesn't included the Driver for AUX Jack or HDMI.

Any Idea how to install it?or how can I get the Drivers?

the kernel version of Image on DVD is: "3.0.57" and the version of kernel I use is: "3.4.67"

Comment: What is the configuration symbol for the sound driver in the 3.0 kernel? Does it exist in the 3.4 configuration?

Comment: Thanks for replying, I don't know what is the configuration symbol and/or how to get it.can you please tell me how to get it?

Comment: Do you have `/proc/config.gz`, or the `.config` file from that kernel?

Comment: sorry for delay in response. I found the config file and I loaded it as my kernel configuration, and I build the kernel. but It does not work.

so I downloaded the kernel ver3.0 and I compiled that and it works properly. Thanks for helping.